# How to fake a nested property by using FakeItEasy?

Tags: unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I have a class like as below:

```cs
public class NodeOperator
{
    private NodeInfo _nodeInfo;
    public NodeOperator(NodeInfo nodeInfo)
    {
        _nodeInfo = nodeInfo;
    }
    public bool DoSomething(int dstRackId, int srcRackId, ModuleBase srcModulebase)
    {
        if (dstRackId == srcRackId)
        {
              if (srcModulebase.FieldBus.HardwareConfiguration.DdfInfo.UserDefine.InstallRestrictions.Position == ModulePosition.Right)
                    return true;
              else
                    return false;
        }
        else
            return _nodeInfo.CanAppendModule(dstRackId, srcModulebase, AppendDirection.Right);
    }
}
```

I want to do the unit test for the DoSomething method, so I write some code as below:

```cs
        public void DoSomethingTest()
        {
            var nodeInfo = A.Fake<NodeInfo>();
            var srcModulebase = A.Fake<ModuleBase>();
            A.CallTo(() => srcModulebase.FieldBus.HardwareConfiguration.DdfInfo.UserDefine.InstallRestrictions.Position).Returns(ModulePosition.Right); // throw System.Reflection.TargetException: 
            var nodeOperator = new NodeOperator(nodeInfo);
            int dstRackId = 0;
            int srcRackId = 0;
            Assert.AreEqual(true, nodeOperator.DoSomething(dstRackId, srcRackId, srcModulebase));
            A.CallTo(() => nodeInfo.CanAppendModule(dstRackId, srcModulebase, AppendDirection.Right)).MustNotHaveHappened();
        }
```

In this function(DoSomething), I don't care if the moduleBase instance is correct or not. Also, I don't care if the properties inside the moduleBase have initialized or not.

So I write the below code to fake the property,

```cs
A.CallTo(() => srcModulebase.FieldBus.HardwareConfiguration.DdfInfo.UserDefine.InstallRestrictions.Position).Returns(ModulePosition.Right);
```

But this cause a Reflection.TargetException:'Non-static methods require targets'.
The FieldBus property for srcModulebase is null.

How can I just ignore the initialize inside the fake class and just fake the nested property which I want?

I know in this case, I can just pass the ModulePosition instead of ModuleBase, but I just want to know how to fake a nested property like this case.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

I need to change all the nested properties inside ModuleBase class to Interface or mark all of them to be virtual.

Then I can fake it.

As the documentation says in [What members can be overridden](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/#what-members-can-be-overridden):

> Once a fake has been constructed, its methods and properties can be overridden if they are:
>
> - virtual,
> - abstract, or
> - an interface method when an interface is being faked